# Firestore observing and receiving sub-document instead of the whole doc? (Time series data)

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I have a Firebase Firestore Database with documents that represent time buckets. Every hour, a new document is created to store my IoT sensor readings.

Each document stores:

- most recent humidity
- most recent temperature
- an array of all humidity and temperature readings for the hour

I don't want to receive the array of *historicalMeasurements* more than once.  Is it possible to observe changes on an element within a document and just receive updates to these sub parts? Or is there a better approach to storing my time-series data?  Thank you!

For reference:

In the ngOnInit, I have a simple document get():

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
// ...
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
}
// ...

ngOnInit(): void {
    let docName = this.buildFormattedDateTime();            // ex: '2021_05_11_22h'

    this.firestore.collection('officePlants').doc(docName)
        .ref
        .get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            } else {
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
}
```

My insert/update code:

```
insertData() {
    let docName = this.buildFormattedDateTime();             // example: '2021_05_12_16h'

    this.firestore.collection('officePlants').doc(docName).set({
        'humidity': this.humiditySensorReading,
        'temperature': this.temperatureSensorReading,
        'historicalMeasurements': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
            'humidity': this.humiditySensorReading,
            'temperature': this.temperatureSensorReading,
            'timestamp': firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
        })
    },
    {merge: true});             // 'merge: true' provides an update and creates the doc if it doesn't exist
}
```

Example document:

*/officePlants/2021_05_12_16h/*

```
{ 
    humidity: 70,
    temperature: 40,
    historicalMeasurements: [
        {
            humidity: 71,
            temperature: 41,
            timestamp: 2021-05-12 11:00:00
        },
        {
            humidity: 72,
            temperature: 40,
            timestamp: 2021-05-12 11:01:00
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I'm open to all options!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to observe changes on an element within a document and just receive updates to these sub parts?

Firestore listeners operate on document level. So if something changed in a document, you'll receive that entire document.

If you want to receive less data, consider creating a subcollection under each document where you spread the data over multiple documents.

Alternatively, you could have the main document only contain the latest reading, and have a `history` document for all the history of that hour.

- `2021_05_11_22h_latest`
- `2021_05_11_22h_full`

Comment: Thanks Frank, I was thinking I'd need to split the data into 2 docs. I'm new to time-series data and there aren't many resources on using Firebase for it